# React way to use forms in html, submit action happens along with ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, reactjs

My usecase is of following.
I have some React component looking like that:

```
    var MyComponent = React.createClass({
        handleButton() {
           $.ajax..... post {this.state.inputData} to server
           error: console.log(url,error)
        },

        handleInputOnChange(event) {
           this.setState({inputData: event.target.value});
        },

        render: function () {
          return (
           <form>
             <input type="text" id="input1" onChange={this.handleInputOnChange}/>
             <button>apply</button>
           </form>
                  )
        }
    });
```

The problem is that when I push the button, the server gets the correct data, no errors in logs and everything seemingly goes fine, but the browser console shows an error: `error, ""` , strange stuff appears in the   address line looking like `localhost:8080?input1=` and the page reloads from the server, loosing all entered data.

Obviously `html` `submit` action happens along with `ajax` `POST` request though the `<form>` doesn't contain any url or other directions to do that.
I changed `<form>` tag in the component to `<div>` tag and the problem disappeared.

But my html developer told that all input data should be handled inside the `<form>` only, and I am very wrong and so went to the dark side.

Sorry for a dumb question, I'm still a beginner in frontend, but what is the right way to handle this?

Comment: "But my html developer told that all input data should be handled inside the <form> only" --- that's not necessary. "but what is the right way to handle this" --- use `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @zerkms Thanks. Could you please give more information about using inputs outside of forms? My html developer says it's semantically incorrect, and it's important.

Comment: "semantically incorrect" is not a formal requirement. Ask them to formalise what is semantic and what is not. It does comply with the standards.

Comment: @Battle_Slug: your project requirements will tell how important it is. Your developer is right about semantics, but the value in it is a delicate subject - http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are handling the request via ajax, you should [prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of the button click, meaning the form won't get submitted automatically.
So inside `handleButton` you would get the event object and call `preventDefault`:

```
handleButton(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  $.ajax..... post {this.state.inputData} to server
  error: console.log(url,error)
}
```

This should stop a page refresh.